# Every local section of a smooth covering map is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, covering-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

> **Exercise 4.37.** Suppose $\pi:E\to M$ is a smooth covering map.  Prove that every local section of $\pi$ is smooth.

**My Attempt:**
Let $U\subset M$ be an open set and $\sigma: U\to E$ be a local section of $\pi$ i.e. $\pi \circ \sigma = \textrm{Id}_{U}$. For each $q\in U$, we prove that $q$ has a neighborhood such that $\sigma$ is smooth. Since $q\in M$, by definition of a smooth covering map, there is an evenly covered neighborhood $U_0$ of $q$ such that each component of $\pi^{-1}(U_0)$ is diffeomorphic to $U_0$.

Now, $\sigma(q)$ satisfies $\pi\circ \sigma(q)=q\in U_0$, so $\sigma(q)\in \pi^{-1}(U_0)$. Take the component $V_0$ such that $\sigma(q)\in V_0$. Then, $U_0$ is diffeomorphic to $V_0$, and therefore $U_0\cap U$ is also diffeomorphic to $V_0\cap \pi^{-1}(U)$ by $\pi$. In other words, the map $\pi|_{V_0\cap \pi^{-1}(U_0)}: V_0\cap \pi^{-1}(U_0)\to U\cap U_0$ is bijective.

This is where I am stuck. I feel like maybe I can use the uniqueness of an inverse to prove that $(\pi|_{V_0\cap \pi^{-1}(U_0)})^{-1} = \sigma|_{U_0\cap U}$, hence smooth, but I was unable to do so.

The following proposition was written right before this problem, so I might use it, but I couldn't figure out a way to use it.

> **Proposition 4.36.** (Local Section Theorem for Smooth Covering Map) Suppose $E$ and $M$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary, and
> $\pi:E\to M$ is a smooth covering map. Given any evenly open subset
> $U\subset M$, any $q\in U$ and $p$ in the fiber over $q$, there exists
> a unique smooth local section $\sigma: U\to E$ such that
> $\sigma(q)=p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that $\sigma$ is smooth. Since smoothness is a local property, it suffices to find for each $q \in U$ an open neighborhood $W$ which is contained in $U$ such that $\sigma \mid_W$ is smooth.

Let $W$ be an evenly covered (connected) open neighborhood of $q$ with $W \subset U$. The existence of such $W$ is shown in [What is the relation of Lee's definition of a covering map to the standard definition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4795731)

Let $\tilde W$ be the component of $\pi^{-1}(W)$ which contains $\sigma(q)$. We know that $\pi \mid_\tilde W$ is a diffeomorphism. Let $\tau : W \to \tilde W$ denote the inverse diffeomorphism.  We claim that $\sigma \mid_W = \tau$ which shows that $\sigma \mid_W$ is smooth.

Since $W$ is connected, $\sigma(W)$ is a connected set contained in $\pi^{-1}(W)$. Hence $\sigma(W)$ must be contained in a component of $\pi^{-1}(W)$. But we know that $\sigma(q) \in \tilde W$, thus $\sigma(W) \subset \tilde W$. Hence $\pi \mid_\tilde W(\sigma \mid_W(z)) = z$ for $z \in W$, thus $\sigma \mid_W(z) = (\pi \mid_\tilde W)^{-1}(z) = \tau(z)$.

Comment: How do I find an evenly covered $U'$ such that $U'\subset U$?

Comment: @Kaira Take any chart $\tilde \phi : \tilde U \to \tilde V$ around $q$ and any evenly covered open  neighborhood $\hat U$ of $q$. Then define $U' = U \cap \tilde U \cap \hat U$. This set is an evenly covered subset of $U$ with chart $\phi \mid_{U'} : U' \to \phi(U')$.

Comment: The issue I have is that the definition for evenly covered subsets from the book forces that any evenly covered subset is connected: "$U$ is evenly covered if each component of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is diffeomorphic to $U$. "  I am not sure how to ensure that $U\cap \tilde{U}\cap \hat{U}$ is connected.

Comment: @Kaira Lee's definition is a bit unusual. I shall make an update soon.